Can field effect transistor s channel s varying depletion layers generate electric flux and control output current indirectly
Since magnetic field lines without need of contact attracts iron filing and drag them closer so that magnetic field line remain smallest.same analogy applied to field effect transistor ions in the depleted regions of channel must generate electric and magnetic flux.can this flux indirectly or without contact control gate  to source current.gate  to drain current ????can poynting theorem be applied here to calculate?Heteropolar FET have magnetic flux effect on it?

Obviously the channel can, and will, create electric flux since it contains charge. If a current is flowing it can also create magnetic flux, as any conductor. Do you expect anything different?

Since magnetic field lines without need of contact attracts iron filing and drag them closer so that magnetic field line remain smallest.same analogy applied to field effect transistor ions in the depleted regions of channel must generate electric and magnetic flux.can this flux indirectly or without contact control gate  to source current.gate  to drain current ????can poynting theorem be applied here to calculate?Heteropolar FET have magnetic flux effect on it?
